# How can i find or install libpython3.6m and python3.6m?

Tags: python-3.6, python-install

I just freshly installed `Ubuntu16.04` and i noticed that the `pip3` support for `Python3.5` was dropped.

So i installed `Python3.6` with the `deadsnakes` repository and created an alias so that when i type in shell `python3 --version` it outputs:

> python3.6.12

For to make another programm use python3 i need to run folling command in my shell:

```
catkin config -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3 -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/python3.6m -DPYTHON_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so
```

But the file `libpython3.6m.so` and `python3.6m` in /include and /lib are completely missing after installation.

Does anyone know where i can get those files and how to install it?

Best regards

Comment: ROS in ubuntu 16.04 does not support Python 3.x only 2.x

Comment: That is incorrect. ROS runs on default on Python 2 but you can make it work with Python 3 when you follow the instructions here: https://medium.com/@beta_b0t/how-to-setup-ros-with-python-3-44a69ca36674

Unfortunatly i havent found out how i can use higher versions of Python than 3.5 as i cant find said files after installing it but i managed to make it work with 3.5

Comment: Those just workarounds, some of them do not work with 3.x, they have added python 3.x support recently if you use ubuntu 20, you can make it run